# Convert Custom date format to unixtime

Tags: java, android, date

is it possible to convert this date `"Fri, 12 Dec 2008 13:20:41"` to `unixtime` (`integer`) in `java`. please provide me with hints/solution . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is. What have you already tried? (Look at the "related questions" on the right hand side for some inspiration.)

Comment: i newbie in java plus i asked for hints . can you help ? links or tutorial will help . thanks

Comment: I gave a big hint: read all the related questions on the right hand side of this very page. Did you do so?

Comment: thanks alot , i will do this the next time .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat pattern = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = pattern.parse("Fri, 12 Dec 2008 13:20:41")
long milliseconds = date.getTime();
```

Comment: Note that it would be worth specifying the time zone and locale (the latter being US or something similar if you're expecting English month and day names).

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that the unix epoch time is defined in seconds, not milliseconds. Following that I improved blackbelts's answer:

```
SimpleDateFormat pattern = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = pattern.parse("Fri, 12 Dec 2008 13:20:41")
long milliseconds = date.getTime();
long unixEpochTime = milliseconds / 1000;
```